# Condition if differences in C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why does conditional if in VB require not handle the direct cast of the conditions. For example in C# this is just fine...

```
        bool i = false;

        i = (1<2)? true:false;

        int x = i? 5:6;
```

But if I wanted the same thing in VB I would have to cast it

```
Dim i as Boolean = CBool(IIF(1<2, True, False))
Dim x as Integer = CInt(IIF(i, 5, 6))
```

I don't understand why C# will do the transform and why VB does not. **Should** I be casting on my C# conditionals eg

```
bool i = Convert.ToBoolean((1<2)? True: False);
int x = Convert.ToInt32(i? 5:6);
```

Also, Yes I am aware that IIF returns type object but I would assume that C# does as well as you can return more than just True|False; it seems to me that C# handles the implicit conversion.

Comment: `IIF` is a legacy VB function; try it with the newer `If` Operator and it works as you expect: `Dim i As Boolean = If(1 < 2, True, False)`

Comment: The `<` operator (as well as all other comparison operators) already returns true or false, so please don't ever do this: `(1<2)? true:false;`

Comment: Thank you all for the info :) Yes @BrianDriscoll I would not normally do this I was trying to show a quick logic of what I meant- thank you though for making sure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`IIf` is a function and is not equivalent to C#’s `?:`, which is an operator.

The operator version has existed for a while in VB.NET, though, and is just called `If`:

```vb
Dim i As Boolean = If(1 < 2, True, False)
```

… which is, of course, pointless, and should just be written as:

```vb
Dim i As Boolean = 1 < 2
```

… or, with `Option Infer`:

```vb
Dim i = 1 < 2
```

Comment: Thanks for that info; very helpful. New development I almost always do C# but I do a lot of legacy conversions/upgrades as well (almost always in VB); was not aware of just IF(x,x,x) in VB

Comment: @alykins: It doesn't exist in VB, only VB.NET, and only since 2008.

Answer (score 6):

This code will show you the difference between the `IIf` function and the `If` operator. Because `IIf` is a function, it has to evaluate all of the parameters to pass into the function.

```vb
Sub Main
    dim i as integer
    i = If(True, GetValue(), ThrowException()) 'Sets i = 1. The false part is not evaluated because the condition is True
    i = IIf(True, GetValue(), ThrowException()) 'Throws an exception. The true and false parts are both evaluated before the condition is checked
End Sub

Function GetValue As Integer
    Return 1
End Function

Function ThrowException As Integer
    Throw New Exception
    Return 0
End Function
```